# Get names of students with maximum points

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-forms

I am in the process of creating a Google form, which students will fill out after attending an event. 
Based on the events they attend, points are assigned to them in Google spreadsheet.

I am trying to see the names of students who currently have the maximum points. My current setup only shows the name of one students with maximum points. Even if there are multiple students having the max points my function is only showing the first max value it finds.

Is there a way to show all the names that has the maximum points in google spreadsheet or excel? Link to my form can be found here. http://goo.gl/UUfvzS

Comment: A pivot table won't do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, try:

```
=filter(A2:A, B2:B=max(B2:B))
```

That should output a list with the students having the maximum scores.

Answer (score 0):

To capture **all** the matches, you must start each match below the **previous** match.  In **F2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B100,E2)
```

this is the *count* of the students with the max points.

In **G1** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()>$F$2,"",MATCH(MAX(B$2:B$100),B2:B100,0))
```

In **G2** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()>$F$2,"",MATCH(MAX(B$2:B$100),INDIRECT("B" & G1+2 & ":B100"),0)+G1)
```

and copy down.  In **H1** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()>$F$2,"",INDEX($A$2:$A$100,G1))
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image: demo]

**Note**

I am using the Excel form of the range rather than the Google form of the range.